# Bash - extract block of lines given keywords

Tags: linux, bash

I'm a beginner of bash.

Suppose I have a text file `sample.txt`, which contains

```
mercury
venus
earth
mars
jupiter
saturn
uranus
neptune
pluto
```

and two keywords `earth` and `saturn`.

The gold is to find the lines that contain the keywords (there is exactly one line that contains each of the keywords), and output **all the lines in between**, including both keywords lines.

Given the above keywords  `earth`, `saturn` and input, the expected output is

```
earth
mars
jupiter
saturn
```

If possible, avoid regex.
Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use either awk or sed:

Using awk:

```
awk '/earth/,/saturn/' sample.txt
```

Using sed:

```
sed -n '/earth/,/saturn/p' sample.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to visit [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-select-lines-between-two-patterns) for more examples and test cases.

```
awk '/earth/,/saturn/' planets.txt
    earth
    mars
    jupiter
    saturn
```

Or by `sed`

```
sed -n '/earth/,/saturn/p' planets.txt
earth
mars
jupiter
saturn
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne 'print if(/earth/.../saturn/)' planets.txt
```

Another solution to get the data only when both the keywords exists.

```
 perl -lne '$f=1 if(/earth/);
            push @a,$_ if($f==1);
            if(/saturn/){print join "\n",@a;undef @a;$f=0}' 
            planets.txt
```